# receive payement bitcoin api like blockchain API v1?

Tags: api, blockchain.info, php

I am looking for a API function as the first version of the API blockchain.info (no API key).

If there are none, I'd like you to tell me where to turn to create an API with a similar operation and a callback.

Thank you.

Comment: You could have a look at blockonomics API https://medium.com/@blockonomics_co/accepting-bitcoins-made-easy-56b54a93ee9a#.3ebu9jg76 . It requires API key, but key generation is auotmatic and no need to wait for approvals

Answer (score 0):

please check this API https://bitaps.com/api/

No registration required, no API keys, simple RESTfull API

To create payment address use: https://bitaps.com/api/#Create_payment_address

To handle callback:
https://bitaps.com/api/#Processing_the_callback

If you need help with development contact support@bitaps.com